# awk check column and get result

Tags: awk, escaping

given the 2 files pri_seq and stb_seq for each number of the first column (file threads)
I have to value the second column in ps and ss respectively and then make the difference
outside the script the awk works but inside the script it doesn't, as if it needed an escape

```
cat pri_seq
         1                656369
         2                859638

cat stb_seq
         1                625743
         2                817088

cat threads
1
2


cat test.sh
#!/bin/sh

awk '{print $1}' pri_seq > threads

cat threads | while read line; do
        ps=` awk '$1==$line {print $2}' pri_seq`;
        ss=` awk '$1==$line {print $2}' stb_seq`;
        echo $ps
        echo $ss
#       ((diff=$ps-$ss))
        echo "Thread $line Sequence Primary= $ps  Sequence Standby = $ss  Difference = $diff"
done
```

it does not value ps and ss

```
(PROD920) oracle@e812stb:/home/oracle/bin/chk_dg> ./test.sh


Thread 1 Sequence Primary=   Sequence Standby =   Difference =


Thread 2 Sequence Primary=   Sequence Standby =   Difference =


Thread  Sequence Primary=   Sequence Standby =   Difference =


out of the script:

ps=`awk '$1==1 {print $2}' pri_seq`
echo $ps
656369
```

do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear but is this what you're trying to do?

```
awk '
    NR==FNR { ps[$1]=$2; next }
    { printf "Thread %d  Sequence Primary= %d  Sequence Standby= %d  Difference= %d\n", $1, ps[$1], $2, ps[$1]-$2 }
' pri_seq stb_seq
Thread 1  Sequence Primary= 656369  Sequence Standby= 625743  Difference= 30626
Thread 2  Sequence Primary= 859638  Sequence Standby= 817088  Difference= 42550
```